# Font looks different between eclipse launched window and jar launched window

Tags: java, windows, swing, look-and-feel

This is the look when launched in eclipse

[image: 1]

while below is what I opened from a jar (but same code)

[image: 2]

And here is the setting. The systemLookAndFeel in this case is winXP.

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.toConsole(ex.getMessage());
}
```

After some research, I found that the default font of JTextArea is MonoSpaced and it is a logical font which means the realization depends on system. But whenever I changed to another font, the line-distance become very small looking not good.

What can you think about? I have tried font and font size which turned out to be useless. If you need other infomations just comment. Thank you.

(I delete the last post because the website I uploaded my pictures forbids links from other sites)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `.setFont()` for components you are using